# Move files into a folder in GitHub (At their website)

Tags: github, directory

I would like to move files and (if possible) folders into another folder, at a Git repository (**trough the GitHub website** - so not using the terminal).

Is this possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A solution is described in the GitHub docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location).

You browse to the file you want to move, click on `Edit this file` and change the path to your desired path.

Comment: Does not look like you can edit images though...

Comment: @Klesun edit how? you mean edit the filename or?

Comment: The "edit" buttons seems to only be available on text files, not binary files, so you can't move files like images with this approach.

Comment: Sweet! Tks a million!

Answer (score 3):

You might have to experiment around but the following might be helpful:

1. This will show you how to move/rename files. You can change the folder path: https://github.blog/2013-03-15-moving-and-renaming-files-on-github/
2. This here will show you how to create a folder: https://github.community/t/add-a-folder/2304

Renaming a folder will be difficult. How many files are in this folder? You essentially move a file. It's a bloody pain.

I'll adjust this with additional tips.

Comment: Straightforward questions are easier to directly answer.